# Checking a user's entry in an entry box to see if it is in an SQLite database

Tags: python, tkinter

```
      database.commit()
      database.close()





  root.mainloop()
  tk.mainloop()
```

Any issues please let me know. Thank you again.

Comment: Use `print()` to verify if what you entered is what you want. The best way to fix this is by yourself, because after you try `print(record,rcrded)`, you will realize why the `if` statements failed.

Comment: Wouldn't `print(record, rcrded)` print the actual results in the python console instead of displaying the message in the separate tkinter window?

Comment: Yes, it is for you to verify the result with what you have typed in you entry widgets. Can you include the output of `print(records)` in the question.

Comment: Ok so where in my code will `print(record, rcrded)` go?

Comment: Before the `if`.

Comment: There's 3 `if` statements so before the first `if` statement or?

Comment: Yes, before the first one.

Comment: I tried doing that just now and unfortunately, there was no difference made as the message 'incorrect username/password' is still appearing, even though i am entering a username and password that is the database. Do you know if there is any other way that can help?

Comment: For me to be of any help, you have to tell the result of `print(records)` before the loop.

Comment: I also corrected the `if` statement so that is looks like `if rcrded == entry_1.get() and entry_2.get() == True:` and nothing is different unfortunately. Are the 3 `if` statements correct; should there be an `elif` or `else` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

An example of `records` is as follows:

```
[(1,2,3,4),(a,b,c,d)]
```

So when you loop through this list, your each item will be a `tuple`.

```
>>>for rcrd in records:
...    rcrded = rcrd
(1,2,3,4) # This is rcrded
(a,b,c,d)
```

Meaning your `rcrded` or `rcrd` is a tuple. And you are comparing a `tuple` with a `str` at:

```
if rcrded != entry_1.get():
      unrecognisable_un()
if rcrded != entry_2.get():
      unrecognisable_pw()
if rcrded == entry_1.get() and entry_2.get():
      successful_login()
```

So the first two `if` is always true, because the string and tuple are never same.

**Solution:**

The possible solution could be to make list of username and password and then check with user Input, like:

```
username = []
passw = []
for rcrd in records:
    username.append(rcrd[1]) # Make a list of all the usernames
    passw.append(rcrd[2]) # Make a list of all passwords

# If statement to compare whether the user entered the correct username and password:
if entry_1.get() in username: # If username exists inside the list
    idx = username.index(entry_1.get()) # Get its index 
    if entry_2.get() == passw[idx]: # If password is the corresponding value in other list
        successful_login() # Success
    else:
        unrecognisable_pw() # Fail
else: # If username not there in list, then 
    unrecognisable_un()
```

**Other mistakes:**

Also keep a note that your `if` statement was *wrong* too. When you say:

```
if rcrded == entry_1.get() and entry_2.get():
```

It is same as:

```
if rcrded == entry_1.get() and entry_2.get() == True:
```

So it checks if `entry_2.get()` is `True`, and all non empty strings are `True`. Which is not what you want to use here.

**Alternatively:**

Other possible easy solution is to change your SQL query to:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Credentials where username=%s and password=%s",(entry_1.get(),entry_2.get()))
records = c.fetchall()
if records != []: # If matching result exists, then success
    successful_login() 
else: 
    unrecognisable_un() # Fail
```

Though this will not identify if the username or password was invalid.

Comment: ok so i just copied and pasted your solution under `records = c.fetchall()` in the `def login_page():` function. Was that where i was supposed to put it? and if so, the separate tkinter window that displays the message 'your usernmae/password is incorrect' is still appearing, despite entering the correct username and password that is in the database.

Comment: Not sure where the `if rcrded == entry_1.get() and entry_2.get() == True:` would go but I copied and pasted the update code and no difference is made unfortunately. Does it work for you?

Comment: You shouldn't use that. That is your mistake. Just use the solution given.

Comment: If it helped, would appreciate marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: No problem, will do.